# How to access SQL Database on Windows 10 Application

Tags: sql, azure, windows

I am going to be completely honest here: I just started learning about this.

I want the app to connect to an SQL database to pull down data. I have researched around and I got very confused. It seems that you cannot connect a W10 app to a database in the same way you could with any other app (using SQL connection and such). I haven't bumped into any useful examples either...

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Asking for examples/tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow. Honestly, I can't quite figure out what question you're asking. Azure API? That's something you'd run yourself. Connecting to a database from a Windows 10 app? Sounds like a question specific to building UWP apps, unrelated to Azure.

Comment: Edited title. Would want help on how to connect to a database from a Windows 10 app.

Answer (score 0):

Is SQL Server a requirement? Or is SQLite an option?

If you can use SQLite, you can actually use the all new EF Core (previously known as EF7) to get access to a SQLite database.

- more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/entity-framework-7-with-sqlite-for-csharp-apps

Comment: Has to be SQL unfortunately. I am using Azure SQL for this and I think I got on the right track with this package; `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;` and then `MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("http://fakename.azurewebsites.net");`.